# Proper course of action for a Community Wiki post that probably shouldn't be there?

Tags: discussion, flags

I was perusing the Access board (my specialty) when I came to this question:

[Sequentially updating values and insert into results table via Access VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665384/sequentially-updating-values-and-insert-into-results-table-via-access-vba)

It's only a day old, it's only got 47 views, but it's been edited **thirteen** times by the OP.  I was going to flag it for moderator attention to get it removed from wiki, but I'm not sure if that's the right thing to do.

So...  What **is** the right thing to do?

Comment: It looks like SO is used as a source control system by that OP...

Comment: @rene or a scratch pad...

Comment: While Servy's advice below is sound, the question you linked is so localized that it's unlikely to be of use to anyone else, and since no one answered it (as the OP put it, "I feel like I'm talking to myself") and the OP has indicated that his problem has been resolved, I went ahead and deleted it.

Answer (score 2):

If you feel that the edits were appropriate, that they were generally substantive, and that they weren't designed to just bump the post to the top of the active list, then you are free to flag it saying that the post doesn't need to be CW, and that it should be removed.  If a moderator agrees, they may act on it.

If you feel that the edits were very minor, and that it was constantly bumping the post needlessly (whether intentionally or unintentionally) then just do nothing, or possibly comment asking the user politely to make sure that their edits are more substantive to avoid bumping posts when they shouldn't be.  If you notice a pattern of such edits from a single user then you could flag a post of theirs to bring this to a moderator's attention, in the event they want to take further action.